# Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add new contact by reading test data from and excel file. The firt row data is created sucessfully. After that for second row I recieve error as "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?"

I have rechecked my code and other test cases are found to be working fine.
I follow the following flow
Go to Base url->Login->Add contacts->driver.quit()

```
@AfterMethod
    public void teardown() {

        driver.quit();
    }
```

I am expecting that data shoul be read and multiple contacts should be added

Comment: Would you please post more of your code? Especially the part where you call driver.get().

Comment: Have answered it, please check and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@AfterMethod` here and `@AfterMethod` gets executed after every execution of the method and in your case, after one iteration from the excel it gets executed and the driver instance gets ended because you have used `driver.quit()` here.

So to solve this problem, you should use `@AfterTest` instead of `@AfterMethod` as `@AfterTest` would run only when all the rows from the excel gets executed and your test case execution has been completed.

Comment: I wish to end the driver instance after reading one line from file and test should again begin from the login. The flow is as expected. Once the AfterMethod is executed BeforeMethod contains the code for invocation of browser and flow till AddNewContactsPage

Comment: Ok got your scenario, so you can achieve that by using @BeforeClass and AfterClass, so use these instead of BeforeMethod and AfterMethod and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading data from Excel and your first traverse being made successful.

Your second traverse will go for fail, because You have expired driver call in @AfterMethod annotation. @AfterMethod annotation will execute after every @Test annotation. In your case, as driver being expired in AfterMethod and if it go for further @Test so it went fail.

In your case, traverse go like:

If 3 excel Rows:

```
@BeforeMethod(if applicable)
1st Row
@AfterMEthod

@BeforeMethod(if applicable)
2nd Row
@AfterMEthod

@BeforeMethod(if applicable)
3rd Row
@AfterMEthod
```

You need to understand life cycle of TestNG annotation, Which annotation will call when.

This is simplest example of it :

[image]

It is best practice to define driver.quite() in @AfterSuite annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you use the driver instance, on which you have already called quit() or close() method, for any further operations.
Just make sure to re-initialize the driver instance before using it again. 
As you have called driver.quit() in @AfterMethod, initialized the driver instance in @BeforeMethod as:

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void testMethodInitialize() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use :

@BeforeMethod

```
public void initialize() {


if(driver == null){
      //initialize your driver(webdriver or RemoteWebdriver)
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

}

@AfterMethod

```
public void teardown() {
   if(driver != null){
    driver.quit();
   }

}
```